# c/c++ image loading/saving libraries

Tags: c++, c, load, imagelibrary

I'm looking for a c/c++ library that can load and save image from all these requirements :

- multiple supported image format
- can load and save huge image (> 2GB) (that often mean a logic image from tiling multiple images)
- can read/write metadata
- have callback mechanism while loading/writing for user feedback

I saw a multitude of libraries but none of them seam to do the job :

- OpenCV
- Qt
- FreeImage
- Boost::GIL
- MIL (Matrox Imaging Library)
- LeadTools
- Cimg
- DevIl
- ...

I saw multiple posts addressing this problem but none of them answer my needs. Do I miss something? I am interested as much as a free or a paid library.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at libGD or ImageMagick?